# C++ Sockets HTTP Post Request Problems

Tags: php, html, c++, sockets, httprequest

Im trying to do a post Request and im having some problems.

I can send the request and get a response if i type the CPUKey and Hash like so

```
GetModuleHash(XEXHASH);
CharStr2HexStr(XEXHASH, HashBuffer, 10);
if (!ServerConnect(SERVER, 80))
    return false;
DebugPrint("Connection Established");
char* Test = LinkChar("POST /projects/xenium-mw3-menu/auth.php HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.xeniummodding.com\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-length: 65\r\n\nCPUKey=%s&hash=%s\r\nConnection: close", "12121212121212121212121212121212", "00000000000000000000");
NetDll_send(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, sock, Test, strlen(Test), 0);
NetDll_recv(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, sock, ReturnBuffer, sizeof(ReturnBuffer), 0);
NetDll_closesocket(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, sock);
if (strstr(ReturnBuffer, "Auth Result: 1"))
{
    DebugPrint("Data Recieved: 1");
    return true;
}
else
{
    DebugPrint("Data Recieved: 0");
    return false;
}
```

char* Test = LinkChar("POST /projects/xenium-mw3-menu/auth.php HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.xeniummodding.com\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-length: 65\r\n\nCPUKey=%s&hash=%s\r\nConnection: close", "12121212121212121212121212121212", "00000000000000000000");

that works but when i actually replace the 121212121 and 000000 with CPUKeyBuffer and HashBuffer it does not send the data. i dont understand what im doing Wrong. Can anyone tell me the problem i am having?

PS LinkChar is basically sprintf but returning the buffer and works fine on everything else i use

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are inaccurate with string dividers (between headers and between start line and the 1st header): \r\n must be everywhere (CR LF in terms of RFC2616). You are using sometimes \n, sometimes \r\n\n. The request w/o body has to be end with \r\n\r\n (last header and empty string)

Comment: i fixed what you said but even then when i do CPUKeyBuffer i get a connection established but takes a while before it prints "Data Recieved: 0". i dont know. using the quote makrs with "1212121212etc" gives the responce almost instant but CPUKeyBuffer doesnt work

Comment: also i dont know if this is an issue but CPUKeyBuffer is a char[16] so its: char CPUKeyBuffer[16];

Comment: "Connection: close" header must be before the body. And Content-Length header must exist (or chunked transfer encoding must be applied)